# Html5 canvas draw line between mousedown and mouseup

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How to draw a line using html5 canvas between a mousedown and mouseup of a button.
Aslong as the button is clicked(mousedown), the line is drawn and stopped on mouseleave

```
<button id="drawLine" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">Draw 
 Line</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" ></canvas>

var el=document.getElementById("drawLine");
var canvasEl=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var line= canvasEl.getContext("2d");
var flag;
var count = 30;
line.beginPath();
line.moveTo(30,30)

function mouseDown(){
   flag =true;
   while(mdflag){
     line.lineTo(count++,30);
     line.stroke();
   }
}
function mouseUp(){
  flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-on-html5-canvas-using-a-mouse

Comment: or here if this one is different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581625/how-to-draw-on-a-html5-canvas-with-a-stylus

Comment: The above links allow user to drawline. But my question is mouseup on a button should handle drawing a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your `while` is causing an infinite loop as no other code will be able to run while your `while` loop is running. Thus, even when you let go of the button, your `while` loop will continue to run. Instead, you can use `setInterval` and assign it to a variable. The function inside `setInterval` will be called every `100` m/s and acts like a loop. Then when you let go of the mouse button, you can stop the loop (the interval) by using `clearInterval()`.

See working example below:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("drawLine");
var canvasEl = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var line = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
var drawLoop;
var count = 30;
line.beginPath();
line.moveTo(30, 30)

function mouseDown() {
  drawLoop = setInterval(function() {   
      line.lineTo(count++, 30);
      line.stroke();
  }, 100);
}

function mouseUp() {
  clearInterval(drawLoop);
}
```

```html
<button id="drawLine" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">Draw 
 Line</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```